# Website security: what does it mean to infect people with silent java drive?

Tags: java, javascript, php, security, web

Someone submitted an anonymous contact request through my website, claiming they have found a vulnerability and asking about a bug bounty program.

They shared that they've found a way to infect people with silent java drive.

What kind of vulnerability is that?
What basic ways to avoid this?

Comment: `asking about a bug bounty program` Are they trying to sell you something?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download

Comment: I assume they're trying to ask for money.

Comment: I don't think it sounds all that sketchy. They (allegedly) discovered a vulnerability on the site, and are asking if you have a bounty program. Many sites have this, and encourage the responsible reporting of vulnerabilities. Yes, they want some money. They are essentially pen-testing your site for free. You can respond with no, and hope you can figure out the vulnerability and patch it on your own, or you can respond yes, and they will hopefully provide you with a detailed report.

Comment: "They are essentially pen-testing your site for free" - or, as Shankar says below, they are looking for a way to infect your site via a browser vulnerability. Treat anonymous security firms with extra caution, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very old one... called the Nine(9) Ball Attack.

> If a Web visitor is new, the victim is pushed through a few more
>   re-directions to land at the site www.nine2rack.in, which may sound
>   like a site in India, but is in Ukraine, Websense believes. The URL
>   inspired Websense to name the attack method Nine Ball.
>
> The final stop for a Web victim includes a **drive-by download** attempt
>   after the malware checks for vulnerabilities in the browser, Adobe or
>   Quicktime software on the user’s desktop. If it succeeds, the attack
>   will download a Trojan with a keylogger component that many anti-virus
>   software packages do not yet identify, according to Websense.

[`Source`](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2009/061609-nineball-websense-attack.html)

### Avoiding the attack.

- First thing will be filtering all of the data you receive from your end-user.
- Set a strong password for your cPanel or FTP/SFTP

Comment: Basic things you would start checking to make sure you are avoiding this?

Comment: Make sure your files are filtering user-input properly and set a strong FTP password.